# FTP connection and copying file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am trying to write a script which can copy a photoshop file from the local drive to a FTP server. The file is opened in photoshop and the script is run inside it.

I followed [documentation(pdf)](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide_cs3.pdf) on page 165.

```
var file_path = app.activeDocument.fullName
var file = new file ("/d/project/test_file.psd");

var ftp = new FtpConnection("ftp://192.168.1.150/DATA/") ;
ftp.login("username", "password");

ftp.cd("project")
ftp.put(file,"test_file.psd") ;

ftp.close() ;
file.close() ;
```

I get an error as the following:

```
Error 22: file does not have a constructor.
Line: 2
-> var file = new file("/d/project/test_file.psd");
```

I am not able to understand the issue properly.

Comment: Good thing to see you tried that. So, what's your problem?

Comment: Instead of `new file(...)`, try `new File(...)`. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are already loading the Web Access library (webaccesslib) as stated in previous pages of your documentation, please ensure you're respecting capitalization when calling class instances.

```
var file = new File("/d/project/test_file.psd");
```

Must have `File` with capital F. The error is saying there's no implementation of class `file`.

Comment: Oh I get it. How silly of me to not see that. I will try and see how it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Now its pointing towards the 3rd line and displays error as  "Error 22: FtpConnection does not have a constructor."

Comment: Check in the documentation, page 164, there's how to load Web Access library. `if ( !ExternalObject.webaccesslib ) {
ExternalObject.webaccesslib = new ExternalObject('lib:webaccesslib');
}`. Requires you to set up some compiled library files in a given path.

Comment: This seems a bit complicated than I thought. So library files need to be set up for each path which will be processed.

Comment: I am also looking into running a python script from inside photoshop. Is it possible? I found this in adobe forum "app.system( 'python '+pythonScript); " but this doesn't work.