# How can I upload a file in an FTP server using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to upload a file to an FTP server.

I'm using Angular but after some research I realized that Angular has no way to upload files to FTP. So I tried to follow this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703594/ftp-connection-and-copying-file-using-javascript) but I didn't have any success because 'new FtpConnection()' is not recognized by javascript.

Is there any other valid code to upload a file to FTP via javascript or do I need to upload the file to FTP via the backend? (I use c# in backend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has no native mechanisms for handling input and output, including FTP communication. It depends on the host environment to provide APIs for that.

Browsers (which I assume you are using given your [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) tag) do not provide JS with an API for making FTP uploads, so you cannot.

(The question you reference is about JS running in Adobe Photoshop, not in a web browser).

The closest you could get would be to write a web service which you could send  a file to via HTTP and then have it make the FTP upload.